# How can I make a Twitter bot that replies to different keywords?

Tags: python, tweepy

I've been trying to make a Twitter bot that responds to specific keywords and makes the bot recommend a series or anime that I enjoy, but I can't figure out how to make it so that if somebody tweets me the keyword "romantic movie" the bot replies with "In the mood for love" or if somebody tweets me "Scifi movie" the bot replies with "instertellar".

this is the code i been using.

```
import tweepy 
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


public_tweets = api.mentions_timeline()

while True:

    for tweet in public_tweets:
        print(tweet.text)

        if tweet.text.lower() in ('Romantic movie'): api.update_status(status='@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' I recommend the movie "Midnight in Paris"!',in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)

        elif tweet.text.lower()in ('Romantic Manga'):
            api.update_status(status='@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' I recommend the Manga "Bakuman"!',in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)

        api.update_status(status='@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' Thanks for tweeting about recommendations!', in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id)
    
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What does "not successful" mean?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, maybe be more specific what output you expect, what you do get instead, etc to make it easy for other members to give tips on what to change or improve.

Comment: As a general remark, the usage of the `in` keyword in your sample code (`if something in something_else` conditions) do not look quite right. Check this out for a simple tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp and consider whether `.lower()` is applied appropriately?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @trs thank you, I've been trying to make a Twitter bot that responds to specific keywords and makes the bot recommend a series or anime that I enjoy, but I can't figure out how to make it so that if somebody tweets me an specific keyword , that i can have different answers to different topics.

Comment: @Ricardo Rosario , Are you able to post a tweet via this python code? Apparently the free API access in Twitter has been removed, although I am not 100% sure about that. I explained the issue in more detail in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76419375/5029509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check like this:

```
if tweet.text.lower() in ('Romantic movie')
```

You only execute the code in your statement, if the complete message is in the word ’Romantic movie'  - for example, if someone messages you with 'omantic'.

What you want to do instead, is to check if the word ’Romantic movie' is in the text.

So you need to write

```
if 'Romantic movie' in tweet.text:
```

If you use .lower() on your text, you also have to search with lowercase text.

```
if 'romantic movie' in tweet.text.lower()
```

Try it and let me know if it solves your issue :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked !! I tried that before, but it was giving me trouble with the second keyword. Everything just needed to be written in lowercase to work ‍♂️.

Comment: ;) Alright, glad it works now!