# TypeError: Client.create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I’m making my first bot but I get this error when running it.

Made with python 3.11 tweepy.

`TypeError: Client.create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Code:

```
import tweepy 

client = tweepy.Client(

    consumer_key="key",

    consumer_secret="key",

    access_token="key",

    access_token_secret="key"

)

client.create_tweet("test")
```

Any fix or suggestion apreciated! Thanks!

I didn't really try anything, I've searched around but I've hadn't understand the solution, I've recently started to take coding seriously (I'm 15) I've code some very simple snippets and more advances games in UE so most concept are new and in a simple solution I won't really understand it, so thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: As can be seen in the [docs for `Client.create_tweet`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet) it only accepts keyword arguments ([python docs for more information](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-only-arguments))

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the text = keyword and worked great, apreciated!

Comment: @ThePangel , Are you able to send a tweet with free access version? Apparently the free API access has been removed. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76419375/5029509

Answer (score 0):

```
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token="key",  # <-
    consumer_key="key",
    consumer_secret="key",
    access_token="key",
    access_token_secret="key"

)
client.create_tweet(text="test")  # <-
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?