Does Tweepy not work with new Twitter API?
I've been trying (and failing) for the life of me to just simply connect to the twitter api using tweepy and post 1 tweet. I have no idea why my code won't work, it keeps giving me the error that I don't have a high enough access level. (tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only.)
import tweepy
from credentials import twitter_bot_keys

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    twitter_bot_keys['API Key'],
    twitter_bot_keys['API Key Secret'],
    twitter_bot_keys['Access Token'],
    twitter_bot_keys['Access Token Secret']
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status("test")

(Obviously the credentials.py file has my actual credentials in their respective areas)
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Tried everything, expected it to post a tweet. Also expected it not to be such a nightmare to use this awful API

You are trying to use the v1.1 API at X. We are supposed to use the V2. In Tweepy that's done with Tweepy.Client and not with Tweepy.API.

I tried the same code but with tweepy.client multiple times when troubleshooting and still got the exact same error

To "write" (post a tweet) your app needs "Read and write access": https://developer.x.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions. If it already didn't have it and you add it, you'll need to regenerate the access token and secret and use the new ones. (Something like that. I'm writing this from memory.)

There's also https://devcommunity.x.com/ with at least one active X (previously Twitter) staff member answering questions.

I tried both of those and had no luck, but I was able to follow a related stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419375/twitter-api-access-denied-for-posting-a-simple-tweet?rq=2) and got it working from that.
It was just handling my other code weird so I used the code from this other question as a base and it worked.

Used the working code sample from Viktor Brešan in Twitter API access denied for posting a simple tweet
No idea why that worked instead, but it did so I used that as a base.

Tweepy contributor here,
Tweepy.org does support both new v2 and v1.1 APIs
It looks like you are trying to pass Twitter/X's v2 API credentials instead of v1.1, you can either create new v1.1 credentials from X developer portal or you can use v2 credentials like this
import tweepy


consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)

# Create Tweet

# The app and the corresponding credentials must have the Write permission

# Check the App permissions section of the Settings tab of your app, under the
# Twitter Developer Portal Projects & Apps page at
# https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/projects-and-apps

# Make sure to reauthorize your app / regenerate your access token and secret 
# after setting the Write permission

response = client.create_tweet(
    text="This Tweet was Tweeted using Tweepy and Twitter API v2!"
)
print(f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{response.data['id']}")

Refer to https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html#examples
